# Algorithm for calculating total cost in groups of N

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization

I have a limited supply of objects and as the objects are purchased, the price goes up accordingly in groups of N (every time N objects are bought, price increases).  When trying to purchase a number of objects, what is the easiest way to calculate total cost?

Example:
I have 24 foo.  For every N(example using 3) that are purchased, the price increases by 1.
So if I buy 1 at the prices of 1 then there are 23 left and 2 left at the price of 1.
After 1 has been purchased, someone wishes to buy 6.  Well the total cost would be = (2*1)+(3*2)+(1*3)

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What's your problem statement? What have you tried?

Comment: I have a very inefficient solution and I am looking for a more elegant one.  Basically you need to check which group of N you are buying from and what the cost of it is.  This is simple if your selection is the same size or smaller than the grouping, but if it gets larger, then it gets more complicated.

Comment: You should probably specify the concrete inputs (maybe number of `foo`s in total, number of items to buy, `N`, initial price).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think that this is correct now...

---

Given:

```
X  = Total Number of Items Bought
N  = Number of Items per Price Increment
B  = Base Item Price, before any Increments
I  = Price Increment per [N]
```

Set:

```
J  = FLOOR((X-1)/N)+1
```

Then:

```
TotalCost = X*(B-I) + I*(X*J - N*J*(J-1)/2)
```

Comment: This is great but, it seems to be buying from highest price first.  All lower priced objects must be bought before you can purchase at higher price.  Also, how would this account for if X number of items have been bought from the total already (therefore starting in the middle of a grouping and at a different price than base price)?

Comment: @Fusion89k Once he gets the formula right, subtract the total cost for the previous total amount purchased from the total cost for the new total amount purchased.

Comment: Oh duh.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I think I've been thinking about this too long.

Comment: @Fusion89k The new formula should correctly accumulate lowest values first.  And as David Eisenstat said, just subtract the preceeding total for starting-in-the-middle calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing RBarryYoung's notation, the first N items cost B each, the second N items cost B + I each, the third N items cost B + 2*I each, etc.

To buy X items: Q := X div N (floor division) whole groups are bought, plus R := X mod N extra items. The former cost Q * N * (B + (B + (Q - 1) * I)) / 2, since, with linearly increasing item costs, the average item cost is equal to the average of first item cost, B, and the last item cost, B + (Q - 1) * I. The latter items cost R * (B + Q*I), so the resulting function f(X) is

```
f(X) := (Q * N * (B + (B + (Q - 1) * I))) div 2 + R * (B + Q*I).
```

To compute the cost of the items (zero-)indexed from X inclusive to X' exclusive, use `f(X') - f(X)`.

Comment: +1: I think that we both got it with slightly different formula. When I was trying to figure it out, I was going in this direction when I realized that I could get away without having to use the `MOD` function by using the `FLOOR` result an extra time.