# Algorithm for maximum items that can be purchased, given price increases at intervals of N

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization

I was looking at the question posted here:

[Algorithm for calculating total cost in groups of N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450021/algorithm-for-calculating-total-cost-in-groups-of-n)

and was wondering how to determine the maximum items one could purchase given a cost that increases by X every N items.

For example, if I have $20 and want to purchase something that starts with a price of $1, but increases by $1 for every 5th item (as an example), I'd be able to purchase 11 of them, with $2 left (five at $1 + five at $2 + one at $3 = $18).

Is there a formula one could use to solve this?

Comment: Given a function f(x) that expresses the price after x purchases, let g be the integral of this function wrt x. The "algorithm" is simply the solution to the equation g(x)=<how much money you have>, rounded down to an integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain the simpler version when we start from 1 and increase by 1 every n times. Here we need `n` for first `n` items, `2n` for next `n` items and so on. Suppose we can get maximum of `k` full groups(total item is multiple of `n`). So our total cost will be

```
n + 2*n + 3*n + ...+ k*n
This must be less than S. So
(1 + 2 + .... + k) * n <= S
=> k * (k+1) * n / 2 <= S
=> n * k ^ 2 + n * k - 2 * S=0
Solving for k we get
k = (-n + sqrt(n ^ 2 + 8 * n * S )) / (2 * n)    // take floor value
```

So now amount of money left is

```
S1 = S-(n * k * (k + 1)) / 2
```

And number of items we can still buy is

```
a = S1 / (k + 1)
```

Total number is

```
k * n + a
```

Money left is

```
S1 mod (k + 1)
```

For example with `S = 20` and `n = 5`

```
k = (-5 + sqrt(5 ^ 2 + 8 * 5 * 20))/(2 * 5) = 2.37 = 2  // floor
S1 = 20 - ( 5 * 2 * 3) / 2=5
a = 5 / (2 + 1)=1.66.. = 1 //floor
total = 2 * 5 + 1 = 11
money left = 5 mod 3 =2
```

You can similarly derive general formula when you start from `a` and increase value by `x` every `n` times. In this case k should be

```
k = (sqrt(((x - 2 * a) * n) ^ 2 + 8 * n * x * S) + (x - 2 * a)* n) / (2 * n * x)
v = a + k * x
S1 = S - (2 * a + (k - 1) * x) * k * n / 2
y = S1 / v
total = k * n + y
left = S1 mod v
```

Comment: First off, thanks for the help!  The first formula seems to work great, but the second one, which allows for variable increases, doesn't seem to work for me, even with the same example which increases by 1.  Might be something I'm doing wrong, but the k value is way off for me there.  I'm supposed to be squaring the result of the sqrt, right (that's the only spot I can see where I'd be going wrong)?

Comment: Hrm... did you test with other bases/increments/intervals?  The new one works fine for the variables used in the initial example, but again fails for me when I try it with other values =(  Again, possibly something I'm doing wrong though...  but for example, when I plug in $20 with a base cost of 5 and increments of 5 every 5th item, it says I can buy 20, which of course can't be right

Comment: @storkupine  It does give me correct result. Maybe you missed some parenthesis? (For your case a = x = n = 5 and S = 20)

Comment: Oh I didn't see the new v/s1 etc formulas before.  This is awesome!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let base be the price at first, after k patches buying the price is

[image].

Let the cost of buying the first k patches be F(k), then

[image]

Let M be the money you have, the most patch counts you can buy k* satify

[image]

After buying k* patches, you can also buy the remaining

[image]

items.

So, the total item you can buy is : k* + r*.

I am sure this is the formula you expect, :-).